# Collapse / Flatten cats Seq / List of cats.Validated

Tags: scala, scala-cats

What I have is a `List[Validated[NonEmptyList[ErrorType], T]]` and I wish to flatten this into a `Validated[NonEmptyList[ErrorType], T]`

My poor attempt is to collect all the errors and then make a new one.

```
val errors = validations collect {
   case Invalid(errs) => errs.toList
}
if (errors.nonEmpty) Invalid(NonEmptyList.fromListUnsafe(errors.flatten)) else Valid(t)
```

I've tried `foldMap` and `traverse` but invarialby run into issues that I don't have a `Monoid` in scope, and I feel like cats probably provides this out of the box in a one liner.

Some of the [older answers on this kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773658/how-to-flatten-a-sequence-of-cats-validatednel-values) seem to be out of date (or at least I can't find the functions they're referring to).

Update:

I have fixed the type.

Comment: Do you have `cats._; cats.implicits._` in scope?

Comment: `cats.implicits._` yes, but what should I be doing to flatten?

Comment: Could you clarify the type of the variable `t` in your example? Is that a single value (something like `Option[T]`)? Is it a `Seq[T]` of values? In the latter case which value of type `T` do you want to be returned? Is it something else?

Comment: It's a case class.

Comment: It looks like I miss something. If `t` is just an instance of some case class, where `map` comes from? P.S. If you want some user to be notified about your comment - you could mention name such as @SergGr

Comment: Do you mean `List[Validated[ErrorType,NonEmptyList[T]]]` instead? You have this consistently wrong, as `NonEmptyList` takes 1 parameter and `Validated` takes two.

Comment: @ziggystar, I suspect that it should be `List[Validated[NonEmptyList[ErrorType], T]]`. It makes obvious sense to have a `NonEmptyList[ErrorType]`. Actually there is stanard type alias for such type in cats: `type ValidatedNel[+E, +A] = Validated[NonEmptyList[E], A]`

Comment: @ziggystar SergGr is correct, I had put the ] in the wrong place.

Comment: @monkjack, could you also answer my question about the type of `t` and the logic behind `map`?

Comment: @SergGr T is a case class, and I validate subsets of its fields independently, and then want to merge. I just realized I had left in the map operation which isn't relevant to this so I have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, [this example uses kind projector compiler plugin for partial application of type parameters](https://github.com/non/kind-projector).  Depending on how familiar you are with Scala terminology, that may not make complete sense.  Basically it means that some Scala methods expect arguments of a certain shape, and you have to help the compiler with that by adding a question mark in the appropriate place.

Also be sure to add some imports.

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
import Validated.{ valid, invalid }
```

Then given,

```
val a = valid[String,Int](1)
val as = List(a)
```

you can use `List.sequence` to convert a `List[Validated[NonEmptyList[E, T]]]` to a `Validated[E, List[T]]`.

```
as.sequence[Validated[String,?], Int]
```

In this case if you use a single String as the error type, the Strings that represent the error type will be concatenated together into a single string.  This is where the monoid constraint comes from that you mentioned 
- it helps combine the strings with string concatenation.  Other error types may work as well, such as `List[String]` or `List[ErrorType]` for the error type instead of a simple `String`. In the case where you want to accumulate errors, use a List of some error type,

```
val a = valid[List[String],Int](1)
val b = invalid[List[String], Int]("some".lift[List])
List(a,b).sequence[Validated[List[String],?], Int]
```

results in

```
res29: Validated[List[String], List[Int]] = Invalid(List("some"))
```

The lift operation is needed above to go from a String to a List of String.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, but had typed out the wrong type. It should have been `List[Validated[NonEmptyList[ErrorType], T]]`. Really sorry for the confusion! Upvoted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [sbt-partial-unification](https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification) or just `-Ypartial-unification` compiler flag (which you should), you can use:

```
validation.sequence.map(_.head)
```

This is unsafe (it only works if the list of validation was not empty).
Now, if you construct the instance first and then validate it later:

```
val t: T = ???

val validation: List[Validated[NonEmptyList[ErrorType], T]] = 
   List(checkQuantities, checkName, checkConsisteny).map(f => f(t))
```

And you still have it in scope, you can provide it directly:

```
validation.sequence_.as(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

I literally just ran into a similar issue yesterday. This is how I solved it (I'm using Scala 2.12 and Cats 1.1.0):

```scala
import cats.Traverse
import cats.data.{NonEmptyList, Validated}

val list: List[Validated[NonEmptyList[ErrorType], T]] = ...

import cats.instances.list._
val validated: Validated[NonEmptyList[ErrorType], List[T]] = Traverse[List].sequence(list)
```

It's not quite what you want as this is flattening the structure into a `List[A]` instead of `A`. In order to flatten `A` to the same type, you'll probably need to provide a `Monoid[A]` somewhere that implements the `combine` method.