# How do I flatten a nested NEL of custom type in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have something like:

```
List(CustomType(NonEmptyList(Error(Bar(b,4,c)))), CustomType(NonEmptyList(Error(Bar(a,6,z)))))
```

I'm trying to flatten it to get:

```
 List(Error(Bar(b,4,c)), Error(Bar(a,6,z)))
```

I tried using `flatten` but I run into an issue with implicit not being found and I can't find a way to write an implicit.

I apologize if a similar question has been asked before but I couldn't find answers to solve this issue.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a simple definition of `CustomType` - Also, it seems you are pretty new to **Scala** _(because you should know why `flatten` didn't work)_, it is not really recommended to use something somewhat advanced like **cats** if you are not familiar with the language first. Have you read _"Scala with Cats"_? If not, I recommend it to you.

Answer (score 2):

If `.flatten` can't find the implicit code to flatten your collection, you can often supply it yourself explicitly.

```
import cats.data.NonEmptyList
case class Bar(a:Char,b:Int,c:Char)
case class Error(bar: Bar)
case class CustomType(value: NonEmptyList[Error])

List(CustomType(NonEmptyList(Error(Bar('b',4,'c')),Nil))
   , CustomType(NonEmptyList(Error(Bar('a',6,'z')),Nil)))
  .flatten(_.value.toList)
//res0: List[Error] = List(Error(Bar(b,4,c)), Error(Bar(a,6,z)))
```

You'll notice that I had to make a few assumptions about your example code. (It helps if you post code that compiles.)

Answer (score 1):

For `flatten` to work, you should strip `CustomType` and convert `NonEmptyList`s to `List`s. The method to deal with `CustomType` depends on what exactly the `CustomType` is.

If the `CustomType` is `cats.data.Validated`, then you should check this answer: [How to flatten a sequence of cats' ValidatedNel values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773658/how-to-flatten-a-sequence-of-cats-validatednel-values)

If the `CustomType` is `Left` and you have a `List[Either[NonEmptyList[Error], T]]`, then you can flatten it with:

```
import cats.implicits._

list.collectFold {
  case Left(nel) => nel.toList
}
```

The same approach can be used if `CustomType` is one case of some `sealed trait`.

If the custom type is something simple like `case class CustomType(errors: NonEmptyList[Error])`, then you can simply use `flatMap`:

```
list.flatMap(_.errors.toList)
```